# Toggling visibility of multiple texts is not working

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am trying to toggle between a couple of texts, where the only one that shows is the one that was "turn on" most recently. For example, the default would look something like this:

Click A
Click B

If you click 'Click B', the text for that will toggle to something else, let's say "You've clicked B".

Click A
You've Clicked B

If you click 'Click A' right afterwards, then the previous text will go back to its default, ie "You've Clicked B" will revert back to 'Click B' and then 'Click A' will be turn on.

Right now, neither of them are toggling, they are just both on.
Here is what I have:

JavaScript

```
    toggle_visibility("t1");
    toggle_visibility("t2");

function toggle_visibility(id) {

    function toggle(id){
        var text = document.getElementById(id);
        if(text.style.display == 'none'){
            text.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            text.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
  toggle(id);
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="t1" <a href="Click A" onclick="toggle_visibility('t1');">
        <h1>You've Clicked A</h1></div>
 <div id="t2" <a href="Click B" onclick="toggle_visibility('t2');">
        <h1>You've Clicked B</h1></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer, hope that is what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if you assign an id to the `<h1>` tag like this and I have added some attributes:

```
<div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('t1');">
        <h1 id="t1" data-original="Click A" data-after="You've clicked A" data-toggled="0">Click A</h1></div>
 <div> <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('t2');">
        <h1 id="t2" data-original="Click B" data-after="You've clicked B" data-toggled="0">Click B</h1></div>
```

For the JS, you can use this:

```
<script>
var isFirst = true;

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    if(!isActivated(id)) {
        toggle(id);

        if(isFirst != true) {
            if(id == "t1") {
                toggle("t2");   
            } else if(id == "t2") {
                toggle("t1");   
            }
        }
    }
    isFirst = false;

}

function toggle(id) {
    var text = document.getElementById(id);

    if(text.getAttribute("data-toggled") == "1") {
        text.setAttribute("data-toggled", "0");
        text.innerHTML = text.getAttribute("data-original");
    }
    else {
        text.innerHTML = text.getAttribute("data-after");
        text.setAttribute("data-toggled", "1");
    }
}

function isActivated(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if(element.getAttribute('data-toggled') == "1") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML first.

```
    <div id="t1">**** <a href="Click A" onclick="toggle_visibility('t1');">
        <h1>You've Clicked A</h1></div>
 <div id="t2">**** <a href="Click B" onclick="toggle_visibility('t2');">
        <h1>You've Clicked B</h1></div>
```

There should be a closing ">" near the place I marked ****. Again, you have not closed your anchor tag with an "`</a>`"

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that I interpreted your HTML correctly (there are several errors in it), but other than that, I believe this solves the problem:

```
var visibleText;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var text = document.getElementById(id).lastElementChild;
    if (text.style.display === 'none') {
        if (visibleText) visibleText.style.display = 'none';
        visibleText = text;
        text.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        text.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This code keeps track of any currently toggled-on 'text' in a variable declared outside the scope of the `toggle_visibility` function.  This allows you to easily toggle off any currently visible text and switch on the desired text.

And here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s0vozdsb/).

Comment: He doesn't want tabbed pages I believe. He just wants the text replaced.